# Is udisks2 able to mount anything the command "mount" can? Can I mount smb shares for instance?

Tags: mount, cifs, udisks

I know that udisks2 can be used to mount filesystems. But what kind of filesystems? By reading information around this is not completely clear to me.

Can I only mount local filesystems? Or can I mount anything that I can mount using the mount command, like, for instance, smb shares using cifs? In case this was possible, can you provide an example of how to mount a smb share using udisks2 from command line? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that udisks2 can be used to mount filesystems. But what kind of filesystems?

- Mostly, disks :-P.  Or rather, filesystems on removable disks / removable media in general.

  - [Provided they are not Windows recovery drives?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333517/how-did-gnome-avoid-mounting-my-windows-recovery-usb-drive)
  - This includes filesystems on a partition of the drive, but not too complex stuff like LVM.  Apparently some form of encryption can be supported though.
  - On a multi-seat system, the drive should belong to your seat.
- But also, entries in `fstab` (and/or `crypttab`?).  I think if there's an `fstab` entry for a removable device, `udisks` forces you to use that.  For other types of filesystem in `fstab`, I think you will also be allowed if the entry includes the "user or "users" option.  There's also a negative option, `x-udisks-auth` that requires authentication as admin - I guess you can use this to restrict a specific removable device.

If you're interested in how e.g. GNOME Files is able to mount cifs shares as a normal user, you may look at `gvfs-mount`.

Comment: @LucaCarlon added comment about how you *can* mount cifs shares like nautilus does.